# Implement CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2019 but found conflict?

Tags: windows, security, rdp, windows-server-2019

I am asked to implement CIS benchmark for Windows Server 2019

What I have in "CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2019 benchmark v1.2.1"
and I found rule 2.2.9 says Ensure 'Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services' is set to 'Administrators, Remote Desktop Users', and The recommended state for this setting is: Administrators, Remote Desktop Users.

However, in rule 2.2.21 says Ensure 'Deny access to this computer from the network' to include 'Guests, Local account and member of Administrators group'

When 2.2.21 is set, the member of administrators can't remote RDP login in.
It seems these 2 rule conflict? or something wrong with my setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are in conflict. Many RDP implementations use Network Level Authentication (NLA). This requires the Access this computer from the network right. As you have learned, these types of templates may have limitations.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks
Some additional information I  found : I told to some colleague in different country, that I was told that if use domain user, not standalone server, this 2 requirements will not conflict and domain ID in administrators group still can RDP. I try this in some of my Windows Server, all within same domain, apply same CIS, however some can RDP, some can't not. I am still checking why